# null pointer error array shortening method

Tags: java, exception, pointers, null

I have the following code that is supposed to shorten an array by copying the elements to a new array and skiping every other one. I keep geting a null pointer exception error however.

```
public void shorten()
{
    // put your code here
    if( samples.length % 2 == 0){
        double [] temp = new double[samples.length / 2];
    }
    else if( samples.length % 2 != 0){
        double [] temp = new double[samples.length / 2 - 1];
    }

    Arrays.fill(temp, 1.0);
    int j = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<= temp.length; i++){
        temp[i] = samples[j];

        j = j + 2;

    }
    samples = temp;
}
```

Comment: where is the NPE? Im not sure how this would compile as temp is defined inside the if/else statements. have you got another temp variable defined somewhere?

Comment: You need to post the full exception trace. At any rate, `samples` is probably null.

Comment: Which line do you get the exception from?

Comment: We do not know which temp are you referring to. The one from your code is not visible outside if block.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each block of this code:

```
if( samples.length % 2 == 0){
    double [] temp = new double[samples.length / 2];
}
else if( samples.length % 2 != 0){
    double [] temp = new double[samples.length / 2 - 1];
}
```

defines a `temp` variable with only 1 line of scope (hiding the `temp` class variable (which I presume you have) for those lines and leaving it unchanged).

If the `temp` class variable was `null` when the function is called, it will still be `null` after these lines. You instead need something like:

```
if( samples.length % 2 == 0){
    temp = new double[samples.length / 2];
}
else { // samples.length % 2 != 0 is implied, since it's else
    temp = new double[samples.length / 2 + 1]; // corrected -1 to +1
}
```

I removed `double[]` before `temp` which declared a new variable.

Also, the for-loop-check needs to be `i < temp.length`, not `<=` since in the latter case it will run the loop for `i = temp.length` as well and thus try to write `temp[temp.length]`, and, because of 0-indexing, this index is out of bounds.

Comment: also, the `samples.length / 2 - 1` should be a + 1 instead.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from Null Pointer, here is another error.

`i<= temp.length` should be `i< temp.length`. `length` gives the total length, since element count starts from 0, the last element of an array is `length-1`

Comment: woudl that give an NPE? It would be arrayindexoutofbounds I think

Answer (score 0):

Try this: I changed your code where needed.

```
public void shorten()
{
    // put your code here
    double [] temp=null; // here I declare temp Array
    if( samples.length % 2 == 0){
        temp = new double[samples.length / 2];
    }
    else if( samples.length % 2 != 0){
         temp = new double[samples.length / 2 - 1];
    }

    Arrays.fill(temp, 1.0);
    int j = 0;
    for(int i=0; i< temp.length; i++){// here I removed "=" because Array index starts from 0 to length-1. 
        temp[i] = samples[j];

        j = j + 2;

    }
    samples = temp;
}
```